# macOS doesn't boot and no Recovery Mode after installing BootCamp and Windows 10

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, recovery

I have a problem after installing Windows 10 on a 2020 i9 MacBook Pro. BootCamp with Windows installations didn't go smooth, got BSOD with kernel security errors (don't remember exact error name), so did SMC reset as suggested in some posts. This helped with BootCamp and got Windows 10 installed after some attempts, however, it completely ruined macOS.

Now I can boot Windows 10 fine if selected with Option, BootCamp driver on Windows is installed and sees 2 partitions - MacHD and Windows. However, trying to boot into macOS from a Windows BootCamp menu or from Option boot menu leads to constant reboots either with the Apple icon or spinning wheel on the screen. Trying to boot from an external USB drive with Big Sur installer also fails - it starts to boot and then reboots after some seconds.

Recovery Mode <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not work (nothing happens, keeps rebooting). Internet Recovery starts, allows to select Wi-Fi network, but either reboots after 7-8 minutes of loading or ends with errors like 2003F. I will try a different Wi-Fi network later, but no much hope here.

I don't have another Mac with FireWire/Thunderbolt port available, so can't test target disk mode, but I checked - it boots in target mode when T is pressed.

Is there anything I can do to restore macOS/Recovery Mode myself, or the only option is Apple's service (not available in my city)?

Comment: On an alternate computer download macOS and try to boot from a usb by holding down option when powering up

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I can select usb disk in option boot list, but it starts to boot (usb led flashes) and then just reboots system. Tried with several different flash drives.